# woocommerce add to cart ajax issue

Tags: ajax, wordpress, button, cart

Woocommerce is probably working properly but I would like my add to cart on every page to be like the detail/single item page ajax actions.

This is what I want:
add to cart -> top of page says successfully added to cart and update total on top. This is how the detail/single item page cart buttons work.

Instead of :
Currently they add to cart and a view cart button shows successfully on the side instead and not refreshing the total on top.

How can I accomplish this.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

If the cart is being updated after you refresh the page, then look at running a refresh after the form submits:

```
    onsubmit="setTimeout(function () { window.location.reload(); }, 10)"
```

Comment: I have the following:

<a href="/shop/index.php/product-category/food/?add-to-cart=43" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="43" data-product_sku="soda" data-quantity="1" class="button add_to_cart_button product_type_simple">Add to cart</a>

Form buttons seem to only be showing on detail/single pages to allow the ajax actions I would like to have throughout the site.